# Count people picker field if it is set

Tags: infopath, people-picker

I would like to create a custom workflow with an Infopath created form, but the problem is I have a list of about 8 people picker fields that I would like to count, only if it is set (ie: a person's name is there and not blank). That would increment a hidden field, but when I try to set the count() feature and set it to the DisplayName of the people picker field, it increments it regardless of whether the field is set or not.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Propably I need more information. But are you trying to count the people pickers from outside or inside the form?

One way you can achieve this is by setting a couple of rules (without code) to every people picker. One rule will increment the counter (another InfoPath field) in 1, whenever the value != blank. The other rule will decrement the counter whenever value == blank.

Will this work? you can always have the workflow reading this counter from outside the form and get how many people pickers were filled out.

I hope it helps.